# How can I place items in different (already existing) columns based upon a css class?

Tags: css

**This is NOT a question about how to create columns in css - so please dont give me any css for doing that. I've just excluded it here for readability.**

I have created two columns in css and I want to place items in them based upon some css class. I think this is possible but I'm not sure how.

```
<DIV id="col1">
   <!-- I want to display everything with 'women' here -->
</DIV>

<DIV id="col2">
   <!-- I want to display everything with 'men' here -->
</DIV>

<!-- this content is dynamically generated in a loop (PHP/ASP.NET)-->
<DIV id="products">
    <DIV class="women">
       Women's product 1        
    </DIV>
    <DIV class="men">
       Men's product 1        
    </DIV>
    <DIV class="men">
       Men's product 2        
    </DIV>
</DIV>
```

**Edit:** Just to be sure I don't want to duplicate the product list into col1 and col2. i want to move them. I only want once visible copy of each item.

So I have two columns - or areas on the page - whatever - doesn't matter for this.

I want to use css to take everything under `.products.women` and put it in column 1.

I want to use css to take everything under `.products.men` and put it in column 2.

How can I do this. These kinds of things are about my limit to css, but I know theres some cleverness I can use.

Currently I'm rendering into the columns in two separate for loops. I want to get away from this for two reasons :

- I dont want to maintain 2 identical for loops - nor move that logic elsewhere
- I want to make an 'iphone' friendly version and i figure this will make that easier.

Comment: This can very easily be done using Javascript.  Also, you can generate your list the way you want it in your server-side script (PHP/ASP.NET).  Are you limited in the latter area?

Comment: Ah, just read your last paragraph again.  You can create a simple function which prints out each div section.  Then, order by class (men/women) then print.

Comment: @stranger - using asp.net MVC so have full control. its the logic to create each item that i want to avoid duplicating (or even moving into a partial control). i'm more concerned about understanding css ways to do this - if even possible. i'm not separating concerns if server side is making cols

Answer (score 3):

You can't do *precisely* what you're asking for with CSS.  But you can do .women { float: left } .men { float: right}, which may be just about as good.

This is kind of a band-aid on your fundamental problem, though, which is failure to separate your presentation logic from your control logic.  Instead of having two identical for loops in your presentation logic, you should have one for loop outside of it that builds two arrays, then your presentation logic should use each the way that would actually be beneficial to it.

Comment: @chaos - the loops i'm talking about ARE the presentation logic loops - that i dont want to duplicate. i've definitely got my control logic separated but I still need to actually put the data on the pages in two places - and thats the code i want to avoid duplicating.

Comment: My thinking was that if you were not wanting to 'maintain' two for loops, it was because they had some code in them, rather than just spitting out the contents of an array.  If you're perceiving a problem with loops that do nothing other than that, I dunno what to tell you.

Comment: @chaos - there no intrinsic problem. i guess I'll have to use a partial control (ASP.NET MVC) when logic is more than just a few lines. or perhaps get tricky and output "</DIV><DIV id="col2">" DURING my loop when i reach the first women's product. if css cant do this thats fine - i thought it could

Answer (score 0):

CSS it's a language used to describe the presentation of the (existing) content. You are 
asking for programaticaly DUPLICATE or COPY some of that content.

You can either use ASP/PHP whatever languaje of choice to generate multiple copies of that content, or use javascript to copy-move-change it.

Actually javascript seems to fit your scenario.

**EDIT:** you have a similar previous question here: [using css to duplicate html elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349322/using-css-to-duplicate-html-elements)

Comment: i want to reposition it. i'd rather not use JS becuase I'm a litle afraid of content 'jumping' when the page loads or some other kind of reformatting. primarily though i want to make sure i'm not not understanding something about how CSS works. if its not possible its not possible :)

Comment: @luis thanks for the link to the other question. the primary difference i see is he wants to duplicate the content. i just want to move it. maybe i didnt make that clear enough, but i didnt say i wanted to duplicate it.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly (but, at this point, completely uselessly), this is not only possible in the current draft of the CSS3 Advanced Layout Module (aka Template Layout), but the spec contains an example [showing how to do exactly that](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-layout/#position) (last example in section 3.4).  So if you can stand to wait a fifteen years or so...

Comment: well it might just get you the accepted answer ;) only fair right. if thats the only way to do it in css. i have to say i'm quite surprised. i thought this was one of the big 'cssy' things i didnt understand. if it doesnt exist then i guess i can forgive myself

Comment: whoa - those are some scary samples!