# Is it possible to duplicate `div` in css?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to duplicate `div` in css?
for example I have div look like that:

[image]

And I need to duplicate extactly like that without using javascript (for).

Somehting like `background-repeat` just "div-repeat" or something else that make it work.

Comment: no, that's not possible. css is just for styling. Also this is not "just one div" it's probably a div with a heading and a paragraph and some text and some spans...

Comment: no, because you would need at least the structure (HTML) for it. CSS is applying on a structure (HTML) and without it, it is not possible to "style" anything. Either you write HTML code or you make use of JS and duplicate the div as you mentioned already.

Comment: something similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349322/using-css-to-duplicate-html-elements

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's no construct like that in CSS.